# How to get a list of specific words in a given sentence, that matches a particular pattern?

Tags: erlang, phoenix-framework, elixir

I am new to Elixir and not sure of its string matching functionalities. 
I am trying to write an elixir function which accepts a string S as an input, which is basically just a tweet and outputs all the words in it which contains a hashtag (#)

```
S = "This is a #bad day for #trump #america"

def get_hashtags(S)
.......
end

Output : ["#bad", "#trump", "#america"]
```

It'd be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ names should not be capitalized unless they are module names. `S` ⇒ `s`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Regex](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Regex.html#scan/3) module

```
iex> ~r/#[^\s]+/ 
     |> Regex.scan("This is a #bad day for #trump #america") 
     |> Enum.map(&hd/1)

["#bad", "#trump", "#america"]
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm!

Comment: @Shubh77 whether it worked for you, you should mark the answer as correct by clicking a green ✓ on the left.

Comment: Slightly improved (and faster due to `:first`): `~r/#\S+/ |> Regex.scan("This is a #bad day for #trump #america", capture: :first) |> List.flatten`.

Answer (score 1):

The fast and elixirish way to accomplish this task would be to pattern match in the filter:

```
"This is a #bad day for #trump #america"
|> String.split()
|> Enum.filter(fn 
     <<"#", _ :: binary>> -> true
     _ -> false
   end)
#⇒ ["#bad", "#trump", "#america"]
```